# What architecture for a TypeScript project?

Tags: architecture, requirejs, typescript

I'm starting a personal web project and I would like to use the new TypeScript release to build JS part.

I'm wondering what would be the best architecture to build one: usually, I like having one class per file. Here, with what I read from official doc, it would be hard to match this pattern (with reference tags or import keyword)...

I would like to know your tricks to avoid long dependency edits each time you're refactoring something.

I know it's possible to compile your whole project in a single file but, for my part, I don't like this for performances (and you're still using reference tags). I prefer using requireJS but with TS, you're using relative paths and strings to import your classes, what annoy me a bit ^^

Feel free to give me some advices :) I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: If you use a somewhat intelligent IDE (Visual Studio, Eclipse, WebStorm, …), it will do all the necessary dependency/reference updates for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, Eclipse plugin is not yet enough smart to handle them (and I don't have Visual or WebStorm).
What about your experience? Are you using reference tags or amd pattern? Do you prefer merging into a single file when compiling?

Comment: I only use Webstorm, I figured Eclipse would already do this too. I haven't built large projects with Typescript so I'm not sure my experience should account for anything. Let's see what other people say!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't documented it perfectly but `grunt-ts` can help you with the multiple import problem (https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/issues/85#issue-29515541).

What you do is type in `///ts:import=filename` and grunt-ts keeps the generated `import` statement in sync as you refactor your project.

You can also load entire folders using the same syntax i.e. `///ts:import=foldername` and even generate an `index.ts` for a folder using the same syntax and them import that `index.ts` instead of importing the folder everytime.

To get started with `grunt-ts` just follow the readme : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#grunt-ts

Advantages :

- faster to get started. Relative paths are hard to type
- easier to refactor (as long as you keep the filenames the same). And when you do change the filenames .. you get compile errors.

Comment: Awesome! I've quickly tested your tool and it's what I was looking for ;)
Just few questions: do you have an idea how to load JS libs? (like jQuery) 
And what about adding a config file to the specified amd loader?

Comment: The AMD loader is the mechanism I used before I wrote this. I plan to deprecate that as I document his particular feature more. For external files check out <amd-dependency reference tag